# Intuitive understanding of Euler's Formula

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation, intuition, eulers-number-e

Thanks for reading!

In this link...

https://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-understanding-of-eulers-formula/

...Euler's formula is explained pretty well.

I understand that multiplying a complex number by $e^{i} = (1+\frac{i}{n})^{n}$ as we let $n \rightarrow 0$ means that we're adding infinitely small copies of the complex number at $90^0$ from its tip $n$ times.

Each time we multiply the complex number by $(1+\frac{i}{n})$, the angle grows by $\textrm{arctan}(\frac{1}{n})$ radians, and the length of the complex number gets scaled by $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$.

However, there's one part  I don't really understand.

Due to each multiplication of some complex vector $z$  by 
$(1+\frac{i}{n})$, both the rotation and scaling are becoming insignificant as we let $(n \rightarrow \infty)$.

But, why is it that the rotation becomes "less insignificant" than the scaling does, so that as $n$ becomes really big, we can say that multiplying by this complex number is only a rotation, but not a scaling at all?

I'm looking for an intuitive answer, geometric and with pictures would be best.

I know that the limit of $\textrm{arctan}(\frac{1}{n})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ radians, so that rotating the complex vector $n$ times corresponds to a total rotation of $1$ radian while the limit of $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $1$, which means we'd be scaling the vector by $1$, but $n$ times, which means its length doesn't get changed at all.

But, for some reason, that's not helping me.

Is there a more intuitive way to understand this? A more intuitive way to understand why although both the rotations and the scalings of our complex number are becoming infinitely small, in the limit the rotations still matter, while the scalings don't?

Thanks!

Comment: The part you’re missing is that $n$ scalings of $(1+n^{-2})^{1/2}$ make a scaling of $1 \leq s=(1+n^{-2})^{n/2} \leq e^{2/n}$, thus $s=1+$ (something going to $0$) while $n$ rotations of $\arctan{\frac{1}{n}}$ make a rotation of angle $n\arctan{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow \arctan’{0}=1$.

Comment: I don't think it helps the intuition much at all to interpret everything in terms of the limit formulas, in fact I think it inhibits the intuition. I find geometric intuition much more useful in this regard, with a strong emphasis on the polar form of a complex number, and its connection with Euclidean geometry in both polar coordinates and rectilinear coordinates.

Comment: @Mindlack no I got that...but I don't know, for some reason, it just doesn't click. Why is adding a really small angle so different than scaling by a really small amount?

Comment: @LeeMosher hmm...sounds promising! Could you expand on it, or give me somewhere where I can look? Thanks!

Comment: Search for "complex number polar form", there might be a Khan academy thing, or something else.

Comment: @Joshua Ronis: the scale and angle variations are small, indeed, but not of the same “smallness” (the scale increment is significantly smaller)

Comment: @Mindlack coming back to this after a long time, I just saw your comment...but I don't really understand it. Pretty much, I want to show that $((1+n^{-2})^{1/2})^n$ converges to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$...although what you wrote sounds promising, I'm having trouble understanding it. The rotation part I understand, but the scaling part...?